# An inline SVG in my CSS file is converted to base64 when is deployed on Vercel

Tags: css, svg, next.js, vercel

I have a weird behavior when my Next 12 app is deployed on Vercel.

To give more context: we have a design system library that contains an SVG inside a CSS module (basically we have a property `mask: url("data:image/svg...)`. In order to make this mask compliant for safari, this SVG also has 2 attributes `width` and `height` both at 100%.

## So what's wrong now?

If I build locally, the inline SVG still remains an SVG `data:image/svg` and that's fine!
But what if I build on Vercel?
Magically, the SVG is no more in the `data:image/svg` format but in `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,`.
So what's the problem here? In this way, the 2 attributes `width` and `height` placed on the SVG breaks the mask visualization.

It would be an easy fix if the original URL was not converted but other suggestions will be appreciated